# "Brexit, Grexit, with the possibility of Spexit"

Tags: word-form

[**"Brexit, Grexit**, with the possibility of **Spexit"**](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/jun/12/brexit-grexit-charlotte-church-kate-moss)

What are they called in linguistic?

Is the form of those blend words the same as [pangry](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84022/paingry-can-be-only-used-as-an-adjective) and [hangry](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/07/20/health/science-behind-being-hangry/)?

Comment: From [oxforddictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brexit) *2012 (as Brixit): **blend** of British (or Britain) and exit, probably on the pattern of Grexit (coined earlier in the same year).* New ***blend*** words like this are a subclass of ***neologisms***, or ***coinages*** in general.

Comment: Nouns?  Rhymes?  Neologisms?  Words?  What quality of these words are you asking about?

Comment: How do you feel about [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)?

Comment: Are you quoting something here? What is the source? Context?

Comment: I suppose there's no point in writing an answer now that both *blend* and *portmanteau* have been suggested in the comments section, so I'll just point out that linguists generally use the term *blend* for this kind of coinage rather than *portmanteau*.  They might also be called nonce words.

Comment: @snailboat: There is indeed a point in writing an answer: namely, to get this question off the Unanswered list. Will you do the honors?